# What is a generic term for the button/icon from which programs are launched or indicated by?

Tags: terminology

What is a generic term for the button/icon from which programs are launched or indicated by?

- In Windows, we have the **taskbar**, on which each *top level window* (XP/Vista) or *application* (7+) has a **taskbar button**.
- In Mac OS X, we have the **dock**, on which each *application* has a **dock icon**.
- In recent versions of Ubuntu, we have the **launcher**(?), on which each *application* has a **launcher icon**(?).

I don't know what other Linux desktops call things and how much Gnome and KDE can each differ.

Anyways, what is the generic term to refer to a taskbar button/dock icon/launcher icon? I am designing an API to abstract jump lists and dock menus / dock tile plugins and I was wondering how I can generically refer to each of the platform-specific application launching mechanisms with a general term.

I don't think `setPlatformSpecificApplicationLaunchingMechanismMenu` or `setJumpListOrDockMenuOrDockTilePluginOrUbuntuThingMenu` would be very good names. :)

Realistically, `setApplicationMenu`? `setDesktopMenu`?

EDIT: Apparently [Taskbar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taskbar) is a generic term.

Comment: Applications on Windows have always been known as applications or programs from the early Windows 9x (if not earlier) days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Anyways, what is the generic term to refer to a taskbar button/dock icon/launcher icon?

Sounds like an **application icon** to me. Application icons may appear in a number of places, but at no matter where they are, these are icons that represent their respective applications.

I don't think there's anything more specific... or more generic (*icon?*)... than that.